# Passing Data from a UITextField in One ViewController to a UILabel in another View Controller

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7, uitextfield, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I'm stuck on something that seems fairly simple and looking for any advice I can get.  I'm attempting to pass data from several text fields in one View Controller to show up as Label's text in another View Controller.

I've been following several other threads here relating to this issue, and I feel like I'm doing it the exact same way, yet getting a CTD everytime I attempt to transition the app.  Here's my setup;

- In Storyboard, created a Segue between the VCs and gave it a custom Identifier ("Preview").  Code for the rest is below:

VC2 (The Destination View Controller containing the labels)

.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *nameLabelName;
```

.m (After viewDidLoad)

```
_nameLabel.text = _nameLabelName;
```

VC1 (Root View Controller containing the text fields)

.m

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Preview"]) {
PreviewYesViewController *pvc1;
pvc1 = [segue destinationViewController];
pvc1.nameLabelName = _nameTextField.text;
}
}
```

Again, every time I run this I get a SIGABRT error claiming that:

> 2013-09-27 19:28:37.580 ****[45758:a0b] -[UINavigationController setNameLabelName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa27fd10
>   2013-09-27 19:28:37.584 ****[45758:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController setNameLabelName:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa27fd10'

Can anyone help me figure this one out?

Answer (score 0):

Your pvc1 variable is pointing to a UINavigationController. That is :
   **[seque destinationViewController]** 
is returning a **UINavigationController** instance. You should check your storyboard to ensure the destination view controller is **not** embedded in a NavigationController.

Edit:
If you choose to keep the UINavigationController for the PreviewYesViewController, then you can do this:

```
pvc1 = [[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];
```

Comment: Hi @mpprdev - Sorry for the delay in response, I'm catching up from the holidays.  Actually my PVC IS embedded in a Navigation Controller.  I was figuring this is why you'd have to specifically identify the ViewController doing the sending in the Root View Controller.  What should I do differently considering my VC's are both embedded in Navigation Controllers?

Comment: @Slider257 - If you choose to keep the UINavigationController for the PreviewYesViewController, then you can do this:  pvc1 = [[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];